# NoSuchMethodError---The method 'contains' was called on null. Tried calling contains(null)

Tags: flutter

I am writing code to get data and display it as list view on screen using flutter, but am getting NoSuchMethodError-- The method 'contains' was called on null. Tried calling contains(null). I thought the issue would be resolved by including the if statement(within the Widget getBody()), as, it points out specific actions to be taken if a certain state is returned, but had no luck.

here's the code for reference--
import 'dart:convert';

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:the_laptop_hub_3/app_screens/login.dart';
import 'addSuggestions.dart';
import 'home.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
class UpdatesScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _UpdatesScreenState createState() => _UpdatesScreenState();
}

class _UpdatesScreenState extends State<UpdatesScreen> {
  List updatesList = [];
  var _currentIndex = 0;
  final tabs = [
    Container(child:Home()),
    Container(child:UpdatesScreen())
  ];
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

   fetchData()async{
    var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?domains=pcmag.com&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=b8010d33c3224b96b552b75eb026e1ca';
    var response = await http.get(url);
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      var updates = json.decode(response.body)['title'];
      setState(() {
        updatesList = updates;
      });
    }else{
      setState(() {
        updatesList = [];
      });
    } 
  }
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        title: Text(
          "UPDATES SCREEN",
          style: TextStyle(

          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.logout),
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Login(),
                ));              
                }
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
         gradient: LinearGradient(
           begin: Alignment.topCenter,
           end:  Alignment.bottomCenter,
           colors: [Colors.black12, Colors.teal]
         )
       ),
        child: getBody()
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        items:[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.laptop),
              title: Text("Suggestions"),
              backgroundColor: Colors.black45
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.update),
              title: Text("Updates"),
              backgroundColor: Colors.black45
          ),
        ],
        onTap: (index){
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;

          });
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        child: Icon(Icons.add, size: 50.0),
        hoverElevation: 15.0,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0))
        ),
        onPressed: (){
          navigateToAddSuggestions(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
  void navigateToAddSuggestions(BuildContext context){
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context)=> AddSuggestions(),
        )
    );
  }
  Widget getBody(){
    if(updatesList.contains(null) || updatesList.length < 0 ){
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.cyan),));
    }
    return ListView.builder(
     itemCount: updatesList.length, 
    itemBuilder: (context, index)
    {
      return getCard(updatesList[index]);
    });
  }
  Widget getCard(index){
    var title = index['title'];
    return Card(
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: ListTile(
        tileColor: Color(0xffadde6),
        title: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 60,
              height: 60,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60/2),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  image: NetworkImage('https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/038Dr5TVEpwIv8rCljx6UcF-13..1588802180.jpg')
                ),
              ),
              
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 20),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-140,
                  child: Text(title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It means that updatesList is null. It has to have a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because by the time your fetchData function completes and insert the response data in updatesList, the build methods executes and run getBody(). And inside getBody() Widget the first line it executes is

```
 if(updatesList.contains(null) || updatesList.length < 0 ){
 ...
 }
```

here updatesList.contains(null) condition gives you the error i.e " The method 'contains' was called on null." because till this point  the value of updatesList is null and you called contain on a null value, therefore, you get that error.

So to solve this update your getBody() if statement to

```
 if (commentList == null || commentList.isEmpty) {
                    return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      valueColor:
                          new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.cyan),
                    ));
                  }
```

Also try integrating API using FutureBuilder, or StreamBuilder depending on the api.

Comment: thanks, it solved one of the problems I was facing. I will try integrating stream and futureBuilders in my app and check if i get a response.